# Authorize.net : The underlying connection was closed

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I am working on a project where I am using Authorize.Net for payment processing.

It was working fine, but today I am continuously getting an error "**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**" while calling any API function. Is this issue belong to authorize.net side?

I am working on test mode using sandbox account.

Comment: Authorize has disabled support for TLS 1.0 in their production systems starting Feb 28, 2018. https://www.authorize.net/blog/TLSDisablement/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line at the very beginning of your code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: You need to be on .NET 4.5 or higher for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

The developer sandbox [no longer accepts connections using TLS 1.0 or 1.1](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/TLS-1-1-and-1-0-Disabled-in-Sandbox-on-April-30-2017-Updated/ba-p/57726).  Instead you'll need to configure your system to use TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

The developer sandbox no longer accepts connections using TLS 1.0 or 1.1. Instead you'll need to configure your system to use TLS 1.2.

To do that just add this line 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

before this line
ApiOperationBase(Of ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse).RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX

For Visual Basic .Net programmers

Answer (score 1):

appears to be problem with sandbox environment only. we are encountering same issue. pointed to Production with account in TEST mode and noticed no issues there.
ApiOperationBase.RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.PRODUCTION;

Opened ticket with authorize.net but no response so far; will keep you updated